# Rails 4: Nested objects not saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a forum and I have forum_types that has_many forum_threads. I want to show a list of the different forum threads a forum type has when clicked. I can create a forum thread for a forum type but it's not showing on the forum thread 'index' page (forum_type_forum_threads_path). There is no error, just a blank page where I have placed the loop. I feel like it's something in my forum_threads_controller. If someone could please help me I would appreciate it...thanks in advance.

**forum_threads_controller.rb**

```
class ForumThreadsController < ApplicationController

before_action :require_user, except: [:show, :index]
before_action :set_forum_type
before_action :set_forum_thread, except: [:index, :new, :create]

def index
    @forum_threads = ForumThread.all #something not right here
end

def show
    @forum_post = ForumPost.new
end

def new
    @forum_thread = ForumThread.new(params[:id])
    @forum_thread.forum_posts.build
end

def create
    @forum_thread = current_user.forum_threads.new forum_thread_params
    @forum_thread.forum_posts.first.user_id = current_user.id

    if @forum_thread.save
        flash[:success] = "Your thread has been created."
        redirect_to forum_type_forum_thread_path(@forum_type, @forum_thread)
    else
        render action: :new
    end
end

private

    def set_forum_type
        @forum_type = ForumType.find(params[:forum_type_id])
    end

    def set_forum_thread
        @forum_thread = ForumThread.find(params[:id])
    end

    def require_same_user
     if current_user != @forum_thread.user
      flash[:danger] = "You can't do that."
     end
    end

    def forum_thread_params
        params.require(:forum_thread).permit(:subject, :description, forum_posts_attributes: [:id, :body])
    end

end
```

**forum_types_controller.rb**

```
class ForumTypesController < ApplicationController

 before_action :set_forum_type, except: [:index, :new, :create]

def index
    query = params[:q].presence || "*"
    @forum_types = ForumType.search(query, suggest: true)
end

def show
    @forum_type.forum_threads.each
end

def new
    @forum_type = ForumType.new
end

def create
    @forum_type = ForumType.new(forum_type_params)

    if @forum_type.save
        flash[:success] = "Forum created."
        redirect_to forum_types_path
    else
        render action: :new
    end

end

def destroy
    @forum_type = ForumType.find(forum_type_params[:id]).destroy
end

def search
  index
  render :index
end


private

    def set_forum_type
        @forum_type = ForumType.find(params[:id])
    end

    def forum_type_params
    params.require(:forum_type).permit(:title, forum_thread_attributes: [:id, :subject, 
        { forum_post_attributes: [:id, :body] }])
    end

end
```

**views/forum_threads/index/html.erb**

```
<h2><%= @forum_type.title %></h2>

<hr />

<%= link_to "New Thread", new_forum_type_forum_thread_path(@forum_type.id), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

<% @forum_type.forum_threads.each do |forum_thread| %>
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
   <h4><%= link_to forum_thread.subject, forum_type_forum_thread_path %>

    <small><strong>Created by </strong>
     <%= link_to forum_thread.user.name, user_path(forum_thread.user.id) if forum_thread.user %>

     <%= local_relative_time(forum_thread.created_at, { type: 'time-ago', class: 'pull-right' }) %>
    </small>
   </h4>
  </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

**views/forum_types/index.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'shared/page_title', title: "Forums" %>

 <%= link_to "New Forum Type", new_forum_type_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

<% @forum_types.each do |forum_type| %>
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-body">
  <%= link_to forum_type.title, forum_type_forum_threads_path(forum_type.id) %>
 </div>
 </div>

<% end %>
```

**models/forum_type.rb**

```
class ForumType < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :forum_threads
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :forum_threads
 has_many :forum_posts, through: :forum_threads
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :forum_posts

 validates :title, presence: true

end
```

**models/forum_thread.rb**

```
class ForumThread < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :forum_type
 has_many :forum_posts
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :forum_posts

 validates :subject, presence: true
 validates_associated :forum_posts

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources forum_types do
 resources forum_threads do
  resources forum_posts
 end
end
```

If you need anymore files let me know.

Comment: can you include your models for the objects?

Comment: @jstim ok, added the models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added/removed some lines in create action of the forum threads controller. Then passed in the "@forum_type" and "forum_thread" after the link_to button in the view.

**forum_threads_controller.rb**

```
class ForumThreadsController < ApplicationController

before_action :require_user, except: [:show, :index]
before_action :set_forum_type
before_action :set_forum_thread, except: [:index, :new, :create]

def index
    # @forum_threads = ForumThread.all
    forum_threads = @forum_type.forum_threads.all.order("#{:created_at} DESC")
end

def show
    @forum_post = ForumPost.new
end

def new
    @forum_thread = ForumThread.new
    @forum_thread.forum_posts.build
end

def create
    @forum_thread = @forum_type.forum_threads.new(forum_thread_params)
    @forum_thread.user = current_user
    @forum_thread.forum_posts.first.user = current_user

    if @forum_thread.save
        flash[:success] = "Your thread has been created."
        redirect_to forum_type_forum_thread_path(@forum_type, @forum_thread)
    else
        render action: :new
    end
end

private

    def set_forum_type
        @forum_type = ForumType.find(params[:forum_type_id])
    end

    def set_forum_thread
        @forum_thread = ForumThread.find(params[:id])
    end

    def require_same_user
 if current_user != @forum_thread.user
  flash[:danger] = "You can't do that."
 end
end

    def forum_thread_params
        params.require(:forum_thread).permit(:subject, :description, forum_posts_attributes: [:id, :body])
    end

end
```

**views/forum_threads/index.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'shared/page_title', title: @forum_type.title %>

<div class="col-md-9">
    <%= link_to "New Thread", new_forum_type_forum_thread_path(@forum_type.id), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

    <% @forum_type.forum_threads.each do |forum_thread| %>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
            <h4><%= link_to forum_thread.subject, forum_type_forum_thread_path(@forum_type, forum_thread) %>

                <small><strong>Created by </strong>
                    <%= link_to forum_thread.user.name, user_path(forum_thread.user.id) if forum_thread.user %>

                    <%= local_relative_time(forum_thread.created_at, { type: 'time-ago', class: 'pull-right' }) %>
                </small>
            </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>

<%= render 'sidebar' %>
```